# Sample complexity of quantile approximation

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, sampling

(I am re-posting from cross-validated where this questions did not get any answers)

I was looking into the sample complexity of $\epsilon$-approximate quantiles. The problem is defined as when having distribution and looking for quantile $\phi$, one has to answer with an element which has quantile between $\phi - \epsilon$ and $\phi + \epsilon$.

I have found the paper "Approximate Aggregation for Tracking Quantilesin Wireless Sensor Networks" which claims that "The work in [27] shows that a random sample of size $Θ(1/\epsilon^2 )$ is needed to be drawn from a dataset to compute $\epsilon$-approximate quantiles with a constant probability". However, the referenced paper [27] is the paper "ON THE [UNIFORM CONVERGENCE OF RELATIVE FREQUENCIES OF EVENTS TO THEIR PROBABILITIES](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece544na/fa2014/vapnik71.pdf)". Not only does this paper not claim anything about quantile estimation but it does not seem to talk about lower-bounds.

Is that a mistake in the paper I found or am I missing something? Or is there some other way to easily see that the complexity is $\Omega(1/\epsilon^2)$?

Comment: Without looking paper it's hard to tell something. Is there link you can show?

Comment: @zkutch: Link is in Question.

Answer (score -1):

Take a specific example. Suppose your distribution is
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=15).$ You want to take
a sufficiently large sample from this distribution to
get at least one observation between the 74th and 76th
percentiles. That is between quantiles $.75 \pm .01.$

With $\epsilon = .01$ we might have to take as many
as $1/\epsilon^2 = 10\,000$ observations.

Specifically, we need to have at least one observation in
the interval $(109.6502, 110.5945).$ [Computations and simulations in R.]

```
q = qnorm(c(.74,.76), 100, 15); q
[1] 109.6502 110.5945
```

Because the 75th percentile is in a fairly dense part of this
distribution, I'll see if I can get by, sampling only $1000.$

```
set.seed(628)
x = rnorm(1000, 100, 15)
summary(x)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  50.15   90.36   99.69  100.09  110.35  150.90
```

Observations matching our specifications are found as follows:

```
x[x>q[1] & x<q[2]]
 [1] 110.1191 109.9076 110.0786 110.1584 109.8379 109.9022 110.2740
 [8] 110.3990 109.8314 110.4582 110.1659 109.9493 109.8731 109.9490
[15] 110.3925 109.9099 110.1190 110.4647 109.8851 110.3344
```

From the summary we already know that the upper quartile (75th percentile, quantile 0.75) is 110.35. If 110.35 isn't exactly one of the observations, there are
likely to be a couple of observations close by.

If I had been looking for the $98$th percentile $\pm 1,$ where observations
are less dense, maybe 1000 observations wouldn't have been enough.

*Notes:* (a) I'm not exactly sure about some of your notation. I guessed that
$\Theta(1/\epsilon^2)$ might have been big-O notation. (b) It may have been
a mistake in your posting here and on our sister 'cross-validated' site
to mention a reference that you're not sure is really relevant.  (c) Anyway, I hope some parts of my Answer are near enough to what you need that
you can figure out any remaining details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the question is about asymptotic lower bounds on sample complexity and your answer does not answer the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Maybe you will have more success getting the answer you want if you explain your notation and give a clearer description as to what you're looking for. Perhaps start with $\Theta = \Omega.$